# What does noautovalidity mean in Vulkan API schema (vk.xml)?

Tags: vulkan

What does `noautovalidity` mean on a struct member definition in the Vulkan API schema (`vk.xml`)?

`registry.rnc` says *tag stating that no automatic validity language should be generated*

The Vulkan registry spec says: *prevents automatic validity language being generated for the tagged item. Only suppresses item-specific validity - parenting issues etc. are still captured. It must also be used for structures that have no implicit validity when such structure has explicit validity.*

What is *automatic validity language*?

What is an example of something that has noautovalidity, and of that example, what was the item-specific validity that is suppressed? and why was it decided to be suppressed?

Comment: https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/13920-What-does-noautovalidity-mean-in-Vulkan-API-schema-(vk-xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consult the [XML schema doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1/registry.html).

`noautovalidity` means most Valid Usage (Implicit) entries will not be generated for a given parameter or structure member.

It may mean Implicit Validity rules do not apply to the given item, although many times very similar Explicit VU is given in its place.

Examples:

`VkWriteDescriptorSet::pImageInfo` has `noautovalidity` because it shares `descriptorCount`. It prevents generating something like "`pImageInfo` has to be an array of `descriptorCount` elements". Instead Explicit VU is given, e.g.: "If `descriptorType` is `*_IMAGE`, then `pImageInfo` has to be an array of `descriptorCount` elements`.

`VkComputePipelineCreateInfo::basePipelineHandle` is `noautovalidity` because the API allows the parameter to be ignored if `flags` does not contain `VK_PIPELINE_CREATE_DERIVATIVE_BIT`. Without the attribute the spec would insist the handle has to be a valid `VkPipeline` (or additionally allowed to be `VK_NULL_HANDLE` if `optional`).

Corner case example:

`VkViewport::x` is `noautovalidity`. It does not seemingly need `noautovalidity`, but in this case it signifies that although the struct has no Implicit Validity, some Explicit Validity may be present in the spec.